# Arrange 1-12 around a circle

Tags: recreational-mathematics

This is a very interesting word problem that I came across in an old textbook of mine. So I know its got something to do with plain old algebra, which yields the shortest, simplest proofs, but other than that, the textbook gave no hints really and I'm really not sure about how to approach it. Any guidance hints or help would be truly greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :) So anyway, here the problem goes:

> The numbers $1-12$ are to be placed around a circle, as on a clock, but in any order.
>   Show that there are three consecutive numbers in the arrangement with a sum of at least $19$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken directly from http://gottfriedville.net/mathprob/nt-circle12.html

**Proof #1:**

The sum of the $12$ numbers is $78$. 
If we add up all the sums of three adjacent numbers, 
we use each number three times, for a total of $234$. 
If all the sums are to be $< 19$, then their maximum 
total would be $12 \times 18 = 216$, which is too small.

In fact, there must be a sum of at least $20$, 
since $12 \times 19 = 228$, which is still too small.

**Proof #2:**

To avoid a sum of at least $19$, the numbers $12, 11, 10$, and $9$ 
must all be separated by at least two other numbers. 
Otherwise, two of them, plus any of the others totals at least $20$. 
Let the $12$ places be as follows: 
_ $X$ _ _ $X$ _ _ $9$ _ _ $X$ _
where $X$ indicates $10, 11$, and $12$ in some order. 
Since each of the dashes is part of some $3$-element sum 
with one of the $X$'s, none of them can accommodate $8$, 
without creating a sum that is at least $8 + 10 + 1 = 19$.

Comment: Copied directly from http://www.gottfriedville.net/mathprob/nt-circle12.html

Comment: @DonkeyKong Here I was praising the speed at which this was typed.. I feel lied to.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Nevertheless, the answer is correct.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I had the same feeling, a proof a minute is impressive. Copied it into Google and what do you know.

Comment: @anonymous It is someone else's answer, with no credit given to who actually wrote it. You can take pride in your Googling though.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Wow, thanks for the link.

Comment: @anonymous It is definitely correct. I was just about to sing your praises for typing such a clear answer in such a short period of time. You should reference your sources in the future :) Nothing wrong with that. You're presumably an academic. You'll have to do that plenty in the future.

Comment: Wow, what a fast impressive answer @anonymous

Comment: @DonkeyKong I am new to MSE, but I am a math student graduate from New York University. I simply found a suitable answer. Cited sources, please do not continue to down vote.

Comment: @anonymous I think in general, copying off sources found Googling is never a good idea. Anyways, I appreciate you changing it. I didn't downvote, not enough rep!

Comment: @DonkeyKong Oh dear, I suppose I will resort to original answers then, although MSE is a highly competitive forum. I praise you for not downvoting!

Comment: @DonkeyKong You have enough rep now. :-)

Comment: @lesguimauves Oh dear, upvoting signifies the answer is useful. Surely my answer is useful? I am fearful of this encouragement of down voting destroying my ethic.

Comment: @anonymous My view is that answers on Stack Exchange sites don't always have to be completely original work, just that they answer the OP's question. Besides, you attributed the original source, so you should be all good. In fact, I liked this answer you posted (I upvoted you), and apparently so does the OP since he/she accepted your answer.

Comment: @lesguimauves Thank you.